# Из двух строк получить уникальную строку?

Tags: php

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как можно в PHP имея 2 строки получить уникальные значения?

```
Строка 1 - константная строка
3XPYVnsT6hc0rbnkMFTCPQ

Строка 2 - динамическая строка
3XPYVnsT6hcYXB0ZWthMzM
```

---

```
Мне нужно получить YXB0ZWthMzM
```

спасибо за понимание...

Comment: сравни посимвольно, если текущий и предыдущий совпадают - сохраняй в результат, если не совпадают, обнуляй результат.

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/WH_8EdlBb3XH7mom5og1yg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str1 = "3XPYVnsT6hc0rbnkMFTCPQ";
$str2 = "3XPYVnsT6hcYXB0ZWthMzM";

$result = implode(array_diff_assoc(...array_map('str_split', [$str2, $str1])));
```

или так еще, если надо убрать совпдающие символы только в начале строки

```
$result = substr($str2, strspn($str1 ^ $str2, "\0"));
```